# Soap Throws java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500

Tags: android, soap, ioexception, ksoap2

Actually I used this code to access this web service [FahrenheitToCelsius](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx)  Method, am getting the correct response, but when I tried to access my webservice am getting

> java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500

error and it is pointing the `transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);                     
//Use this to add parameters                              
request.addProperty("username",usr);
request.addProperty("password",pass);
request.addProperty("backOfficePartnerId",id);

//Declare the version of the SOAP request
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

envelope.dotNet = true;

try {
    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    Log.i("bodyout", "" + envelope.bodyOut.toString());

    transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);      

    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    System.out.println("result IN F TO C::"+result);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Am getting the correct response till here. I debuged and checked the values am sending the body out that is correct and in response for me the bodyin is null.

Comment: Have you tried to access your Webservice anywhere else? It looks like your WebService is crashing with your request.

Comment: @AitorCalderon::I tried the same url in Iphone and got the output,,

Comment: What external libraries are you using? I had a similar issue and I think it might be libraries. I was using ksoap2, httpmime4.0.1, and apache-mime4j-0.6 and once I deleted those last 2 the errors went away

Comment: @Roman:: Thanks dude,,,, probz with the soap action and method name solved .i.e., input am sending is wrong. solved it,,,

Comment: I didn't get what you did to resolve this? I am able to get to any other public soap services. The one which I am suppose to use keep throwing me error on same call you mentioned. I have checked 10 times that my request parameters, namespace, url, method are correct. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you find a solution?, I'm getting same error

Comment: @seleucia:: I have send a wrong method name.. Kindly check whether you are sending the correct input....

Comment: @JeevaNandhan I found out problem, i did similar mistake.  Thank youu

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Status: 500 is an internal server error and it probably has something to do with your .NET server side coding.

Answer (score 0):

change VER10 to VER11.
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.**VER11**) working for me

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot but couldn't find any specific solution.
I solved my problem by downloading new server package(of same version) and replaced the previous  server package by new one .(about Apache tomcat 7)