# how to Call ksoap web service from android?

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I have a small confusion, in our mobile app an ksoap web service called from ios like below : and getting data properly. Here in the following web service you can see from following code, there are some parameters need to pass to the web service.

```
 -(void)callwebservice{
    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Body><Calculate xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><inputRate>%@</inputRate><rateFrequency xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FusionPeople.MobileContractor.DomainModel\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><a:RateFrequencyId>0</a:RateFrequencyId><a:RateFrequencyName>%@</a:RateFrequencyName></rateFrequency><nonTaxableExpense>%@</nonTaxableExpense><expenseFrequency xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FusionPeople.MobileContractor.DomainModel\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><a:RateFrequencyId>0</a:RateFrequencyId><a:RateFrequencyName>%@</a:RateFrequencyName></expenseFrequency></Calculate></s:Body></s:Envelope>\n",txtinputrate.text,lblrate.text,txtexpenses.text,lblexpense.text
                             ];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@MobileContractorCalculationService.svc",[MobileContractorAppDelegate getstrIpAddress] ]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMessage length]];
    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/IMobileContractorCalculationService/Calculate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if( theConnection ){
        webData = [NSMutableData data] ;
    }
}
```

And other side at android side i have tried so many ways to call this web service and pass data to web service .But every time i getting server side error code: 415, Please somebody help me and tell me how to pass this hierarchical data to this type of ksoap web service....

I have tried following code  :

```
try {

             SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

             request.addProperty("inputRate", 1000);

             SoapObject rate = new SoapObject(SOAP_ACTION, "rateFrequency");

             PropertyInfo info = new PropertyInfo();
             info.setName("RateFrequencyId");
             info.setValue(0);
             rate.addProperty(info);

             PropertyInfo info2 = new PropertyInfo();
             info2.setName("RateFrequencyName");
             info2.setValue("Hourly");
             rate.addProperty(info2);

             request.addProperty("rateFrequency", rate);

             request.addProperty("nonTaxableExpense", 500);

             SoapObject exp = new SoapObject(SOAP_ACTION, "expenseFrequency");

             PropertyInfo info3 = new PropertyInfo();
             info3.setName("RateFrequencyId");
             info3.setValue(0);
             exp.addProperty(info3);

             PropertyInfo info4 = new PropertyInfo();
             info4.setName("RateFrequencyName");
             info4.setValue("Hourly");
             exp.addProperty(info4);

             request.addProperty("expenseFrequency", exp);

             Log.v("", "=========== Request : " + request);

             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new
             SoapSerializationEnvelope(
             SoapEnvelope.VER11);
             envelope.dotNet = true;
             envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

             try {
             androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
             SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
             Log.v("myApp",
             "========================== Res" + response.toString());



             } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

But it getting following error :

```
    09-09 14:33:18.054: V/(957): =========== Request : Calculate{inputRate=1000; rateFrequency=rateFrequency{RateFrequencyId=0; RateFrequencyName=Hourly; }; nonTaxableExpense=500; expenseFrequency=expenseFrequency{RateFrequencyId=0; RateFrequencyName=Hourly; }; }
09-09 14:33:30.264: W/System.err(957): java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500
09-09 14:33:30.264: W/System.err(957):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:195)
09-09 14:33:30.264: W/System.err(957):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
09-09 14:33:30.264: W/System.err(957):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:111)
09-09 14:33:30.264: W/System.err(957):  at com.example.ksoapwebserviceexample.MainActivity.call(MainActivity.java:318)
09-09 14:33:30.264: W/System.err(957):  at com.example.ksoapwebserviceexample.MainActivity$testReq.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:185)
09-09 14:33:30.264: W/System.err(957):  at com.example.ksoapwebserviceexample.MainActivity$testReq.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-09 14:33:30.274: W/System.err(957):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-09 14:33:30.274: W/System.err(957):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-09 14:33:30.274: W/System.err(957):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-09 14:33:30.274: W/System.err(957):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
09-09 14:33:30.274: W/System.err(957):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
09-09 14:33:30.274: W/System.err(957):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: you must add your code ( the java code, not the ios one ) , and the stack trace of errors that you got, otherwise, here is a tutorial about how to use ksoap2 : http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/android-calling-a-web-service-using-ksoap2-passing-values-to-a-web-service/

Comment: the code posted does not look like java code. looks like related to ios

Comment: yes @Raghunandan actually i have posted is ios code and i m confuse how to use it with andorid ?

Comment: @user2753221 post your android code.

Comment: i have posted my android code please refresh your page

Comment: @user2753221 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809391/soap-throws-java-io-ioexception-http-request-failed-http-status-500. your code looks fine

Comment: SOAP (Simple Object Access Protocol) is protocol not service

Answer (score 6):

try Following Samples.

1. [ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html)
2. [android-calling-a-web-service-using-ksoap2-passing-values-to-a-web-service](http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/android-calling-a-web-service-using-ksoap2-passing-values-to-a-web-service/)

Hope this will solve your problem

I use the following method to call ksoap web-servie

```
public String getServiceResponse(String nameSpace, String methodName,
        String soapAction, String Url, List<PropertyInfo> mPropertyInfo) {

    String mResponse = "";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(nameSpace, methodName);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    if (mPropertyInfo != null) {
        for (PropertyInfo propertyInfo : mPropertyInfo) {
            request.addProperty(propertyInfo);
        }
    }
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(Url);
    ht.debug = true;
    try {
        ht.call(soapAction, envelope);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mResponse = envelope.getResponse().toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mResponse;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time @Khudabaks ...but what wrong with my code....can you tell me ?

Comment: The error you are getting is related to unsupported media type. it occurs when content-type is differ from what webservice is asking and in which type you are sending.
`hconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");` as my webservice is getting xml so i set content-type as xml.

Comment: sure  :  private final String URL = "http://brainteclabs.com:8180/MobileContractorCalculationService.svc";

Comment: no no sory but it is not local url live URL check this URL :  http://brainteclabs.com:8180/MobileContractorCalculationService.svc