# Autocomplete textview data Fetch from ksoap webservice, Using Search icon Onclick request with asynchronous task

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-ksoap2

How can we fetch Data from ksoap web service, show in Android Autocomplete textview search suggestion, using Onclick Search button.

Comment: Do you have a code example which you can provide for better understanding?

Comment: i have added in auto complete textview in my code, But  not showing the data

Comment: It is always a good idea to post the existing code in your question.

Comment: I have posted my code ,check & reply me.please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code For Autocomplete textview data Fetch from ksoap webservice, Using Search icon Click Request .

it Will Show the Suggestion from Ksoap WebService.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.LabeledIntent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class FindCity extends ActionBarActivity implementsOnItemClickListener, OnClickListener 
        {

    AutoCompleteTextView SearchAutoComplte;
    Button searchicon;

    // for WebService 
        private static final String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http:*************";
        private static final String NAMESPACE2 = "http:********************";
        private static final String URL2 = "http:****************";
        private static final String METHOD_NAME2 = "**********";
        private String TAG2 = "City";
        public static String Status_Response = "";


           public String Autocomplete_SearchValue;
           public  String  Cityname;

           String[] CITYNAME;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SearchAutoComplte=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        Autocomplete_SearchValue =SearchAutoComplte.getText().toString();

        searchicon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Search_iconimage);

        searchicon.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.Search_iconimage:



                AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                // Call execute
                task.execute();

            break;

        }

    }

        private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                Log.i(TAG2, "doInBackground");
                try {

                    getdata(Autocomplete_SearchValue);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error caught in do in background", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                return null;

                // return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                Log.i(TAG2, "onPostExecute");

                try {



                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindCity.this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, CITYNAME);

                    //SearchEdittext.setThreshold(1);
                    SearchAutoComplte.setAdapter(adapter);




                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG2, "Error");

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                Log.i(TAG2, "onPreExecute");

            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                Log.i(TAG2, "onProgressUpdate");
            }

        }

        public void getdata(String SearchValue) 
        {
            // Create request
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE2, METHOD_NAME2);



            PropertyInfo pi4 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi4.setName("City");
            pi4.setValue(SearchValue);// get the string that is to be sent to the webservice
            pi4.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pi4);

            // Create envelope
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            // Set output SOAP object
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            // Create HTTP call object
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL2);

            try {
                // Invole web service
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope);
                // Get the response
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

                //Converting string to Array list
                  ArrayList<String> Servciecityname_arr= new ArrayList<String>();


                if ((response.toString()).contains("{")) 
                {

                    SoapObject rep = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(rep.getPropertyAsString(0));
                    for (int i = 0; i < jr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.get(i);


                           Cityname = jb.getString("CityName123");


                           Servciecityname_arr.add(Cityname);

                    }

                    CITYNAME = new String[Servciecityname_arr.size()];
                    CITYNAME = Servciecityname_arr.toArray(CITYNAME);


                } 
                else
                {
                    Status_Response = response.toString();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG2, "Error in catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

EditText not showing suggestion.

AutoCompleteTextView provides suggestion in editText.

First you need to parse data from server.
Then make adapter with that data and set in AutoCompleteTextView.

For more information I suggest you to check [this blog](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm/)

And for your reference also check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694605/how-to-call-ksoap-web-service-from-android) to parse ksoap Webservice.

Comment: But this link showing address location , in My problem show specified data fetch from ksoap webservcie, then show in autocomplete textview, iam not finding any code like this.

Comment: make sure you are parsing proper from webservice and filling exact data what you want to show in autocompletetextview.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getSignupdata(String SearchValue, String CityLocation) 
    {
        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE2, METHOD_NAME2);

        PropertyInfo pi3 = new PropertyInfo();
        pi3.setName("search");
        pi3.setValue(SearchValue);// get the string that is to be sent to the webservice
        pi3.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi3);

        PropertyInfo pi4 = new PropertyInfo();
        pi4.setName("City");
        pi4.setValue(CityLocation);// get the string that is to be sent to the webservice
        pi4.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi4);

        // Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL2);

        try {
            // Invole web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope);
            // Get the response
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            if ((response.toString()).contains("{")) 
            {
                // JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(response);
                SoapObject rep = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(rep.getPropertyAsString(0));
                for (int i = 0; i < jr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.get(i);



                       ServiceCenterName = jb.getString("CenterName");



                        String strArray[] = ServiceCenterName.split(" ");

                System.out.println("String converted to String array");

                //print elements of String array
                for(int i=0; i < strArray.length; i++)
                {
                        System.out.println(strArray[i]);
                }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, strArray);

            SearchEdittext.setThreshold(1);
            SearchEdittext.setAdapter(adapter)


                }
            } 
            else
            {
                Status_Response_FindStores_Landing = response.toString();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG2, "Error in catch");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: this is my code iam not getting data in autocomplete textview