# Can I add autocomplete feature to my alert input dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout

My question is simple, I am working on a navigation app and, I use alert input dialog for taking input when a user wants to search for a place on my map, so how can I make my input field auto-complete?

Comment: See this https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete

Comment: see this


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406833/autocomplete-textview-data-fetch-from-ksoap-webservice-using-search-icon-onclic/29444607#29444607

This link may useful for your question.