# android-AutoCompleteTextView is not displaying text

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

this is how I fill my adapter:

```
class Ajax5 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {// JSON STARTS HERE
    protected ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> pickpinn;
    JSONObject json;

    public Ajax5() {
        super();
        parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pickpinn = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        Spots_tab1_json sh = new Spots_tab1_json();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("myaddress/getPredicts.php", Spots_tab1_json.GET);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                Log.v("this", e1.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("contacts");
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> valuePairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject tempObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                valuePairs.put("id", tempObj.getString("id"));
                valuePairs.put("name", tempObj.getString("name"));
                pickpinn.add(valuePairs);
            }
            if (pickpinn != null && pickpinn.size() > 0) {
                SimpleAdapter sp5_adapter = new SimpleAdapter(FistActiivty.this, pickpinn,
                        R.layout.newcardialogitme, new String[] { "names" }, new int[] { R.id.textView1 });
                etSearch.setAdapter(sp5_adapter);
                etSearch.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

                    }
                });
                sp5_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("this", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this is an image of the autocompletetextview ,as you can see, it returns the rows but it doesn't display the values :

[image]

this is the textview xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="9dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/newcardialogitem" >

</TextView>
```

could you help me , why it doesn't display the texts ?

thanks

Comment: this is how you should fill your adapter:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Comment: [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29444607/4447803 try this link already  autocompletetextview from Webservice.

Comment: @Mano this is **Auto**CompleteTextView, it is **Auto**, not with the Button's click