# How to pass soap request in android

Tags: android, wsdl, ksoap

This is my WSDL file view.

```
    <s:element name="ManageUser">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Scenario" type="tns:ManageUserScenario"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Language" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Userguid" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Username" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Email" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Firstname" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Lastname" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Address" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="District" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Province" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Country" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Postcode" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Phone" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Newsletter" type="tns:SubscribeNewsletter"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:simpleType name="ManageUserScenario">
<s:restriction base="s:string">
<s:enumeration value="Create"/>
<s:enumeration value="Update"/>
</s:restriction>
</s:simpleType>
<s:simpleType name="SubscribeNewsletter">
<s:restriction base="s:string">
<s:enumeration value="X"/>
<s:enumeration value="N"/>
</s:restriction>
</s:simpleType>
```

How can i set request for this. This is my code where i am getting no response but warnings. Please tell me where i am wrong. My code:

```
try {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);

                request.addProperty("Scenario", "Create");
                request.addProperty("Language", "en");
                request.addProperty("Username", "abc");
                request.addProperty("Email", "abc@gmail.com");
                request.addProperty("Password", "abc");
                request.addProperty("Firstname", "kumar");
                request.addProperty("Lastname", "aryan");
                request.addProperty("Userguid", "");
                request.addProperty("Phone", "0000000000");
                request.addProperty("Address", "");
                request.addProperty("District", "");
                request.addProperty("Province", "");
                request.addProperty("Country", "India");
                request.addProperty("Postcode", "");
                request.addProperty("Newsletter", "X");

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SOAP_VERSION);

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                envelope.dotNet = true;

                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                Log.e("Try Block 1", envelope + " - " + request);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                SoapObject result1 = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

Also i am getting this in log:

```
    W/System.err(32420): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:TEXT  To register an ...@2:166 in java.io.InputStreamReader@42885270) 
: at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2045)
: at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:275)
: at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:389)
: at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:273)
: at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:389)
: at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:273)
: at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:389)
: at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:273)
: at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:389)
: at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:273)
: at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:389)
: at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:151)
: at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
: at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:118)
: at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:253)
: at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
: at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:111)
: at com.chilindo.SignUpActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(SignUpActivity.java:193)
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29444607/4447803 try lik this, in this link i have used soap request only

Comment: You can check [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-soapcl/listing1.html)

Comment: Thanks for help. let me check if these links work for me or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is the complex way of using wsdl api.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(NAMESPACE + "users.asmx");

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;

                String bodyOut = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
                bodyOut += "<soap:Body><" + METHOD + " xmlns=\""
                        + NAMESPACE + "\">";
                bodyOut += "<Scenario>" + "Create"
                        + "</Scenario><Language>"
                        + R.string.language
                        + "</Language>"
                        + "<Userguid>"
                        + ""
                        + "</Userguid><Username>"
                        + str_username
                        + "</Username>"
                        + "<Email>"
                        + str_email
                        + "</Email> <Password>"
                        + str_password
                        + "</Password><Firstname>"
                        + str_first_name
                        + "</Firstname>"
                        + " <Lastname>"
                        + str_last_name
                        + "</Lastname><Address>"
                        + ""
                        + "</Address><District>"
                        + ""
                        + "</District>"
                        + "<Province>"
                        + ""
                        + "</Province><Country>"
                        + str_country
                        + "</Country><Postcode>"
                        + ""
                        + "</Postcode>"
                        + "<Phone>"
                        + str_phone
                        + "</Phone><Newsletter>"
                        + news_letter
                        + "</Newsletter>";
                bodyOut += "</" + METHOD + "></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

                String xml2 = bodyOut;
                // System.out.println("Body " + xml2);
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(xml2, HTTP.UTF_8);
                se.setContentType("text/xml");
                httpPost.addHeader(SOAP_ACTION, NAMESPACE + "users.asmx");
                httpPost.setEntity(se);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String xml = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
```

Comment: Thank you Nikks... Its worked for me. You are life savior for me

Comment: Your Welcome... Keep Coding... Cheers... :)

Comment: you are awesome .. i was trying to get response of my WSDL url, finally i  got with this simple solution....

Answer (score 1):

This is how you make a request with SOAP API and then get a response. Following is the most simple format for getting data through SOAP. Hope it helps ...

```
public class WebService
{

public static SoapObject getSoapResponse(String email, String password, String Key)
{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    PropertyInfo EmailPI = new PropertyInfo();
    EmailPI.setName("email");
    EmailPI.setValue(email);
    EmailPI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(EmailPI);

    PropertyInfo passwordApi = new PropertyInfo();
    passwordApi.setName("password");
    passwordApi.setValue(password);
    passwordApi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passwordApi);

    PropertyInfo apiKeyParam=new PropertyInfo();
    apiKeyParam.setName("Key");
    apiKeyParam.setType(String.class);
    apiKeyParam.setValue(apiKey);
    request.addProperty(apiKeyParam);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    SoapObject response = null;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return response;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it also doesn;t work for me. have any other way to do so?

Comment: i have updated my question with error i am facing. please review it.