# How to parse objects of xml type in Android

Tags: android, parsing

I am having problem in parsing the following response. It contains n number os objects in an object with xml format. How should I parse them?

```
{
  "000002": {
    "ref": "000002",
    "barcodes": {
      "data": "<sku><barcode>000002014001</barcode><path></path><alias_code></alias_code><color>GREY</color><price>10.50</price><size>S</size><stock>0</stock></sku><sku><barcode>000002014002</barcode><path></path><alias_code></alias_code><color>GREY</color><price>10.50</price><size>M</size><stock>2</stock></sku><sku><barcode>000002014003</barcode><path></path><alias_code></alias_code><color>GREY</color><price>10.50</price><size>L</size><stock>1</stock></sku><sku>,
      "#datatype": "xml"
    }
  },
  "000012": {
    "ref": "000012",
    "barcodes": {
      "data": "<sku><barcode>000012030001</barcode><path></path><alias_code></alias_code><color>BLUE</color><price>19.99</price><size>S</size><stock>1</stock></sku><sku><barcode>000012030002</barcode><path></path><alias_code></alias_code><color>BLUE</color><price>19.99</price><size>M</size><stock>3</stock></sku><sku>,
      "#datatype": "xml"
    }
  },
"pager": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "limit": 50,
    "total": "354",
    "pages": 8
  }
}
```

I am trying the below parsing code, but it is throwing exceptions.
parsing code:

```
        ArrayList<Model_BarcodeDetail> group_list = null;
        ArrayList<Model_BarcodeList_Child> child_list = null;
        try {
            group_list = new ArrayList<Model_BarcodeDetail>();

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            result = httpClient.execute(postRequest, responseHandler);
            JSONObject jsonarray = new JSONObject(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                child_list = new ArrayList<Model_BarcodeList_Child>();
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println("---json" + jsonObj);
                Model_BarcodeDetail data = new Model_BarcodeDetail();
                data.setReference((jsonObj.getString("ref")));
                System.out.println("======refinprsing--"+data.getReference());
                data.setName((jsonObj.getString("name")));
                data.setDescription((jsonObj.getString("desc")));
                data.setPrice((jsonObj.getString("price")));
                data.setTotal(data.getPrice().trim());
                data.setFixedTotal(data.getPrice().trim());
                JSONArray obj2 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("skus");

                for (int j = 0; j < obj2.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject json = obj2.getJSONObject(j);
                    System.out.println("---json" + json);
                    Model_BarcodeList_Child data2 = new Model_BarcodeList_Child();
                    data2.setBarcode((json.getString("barcode")));
                    System.out.println("=======barcodeinparsing: "+data2.getBarcode());
                    data2.setColor((json.getString("color")));
                    data2.setSize((json.getString("size")));
                    data2.setPrice(json.getString("price"));
                    data2.setStock(json.getString("stock"));
                    data2.setAlis_code(json.getString("alias_code"));
                    child_list.add(data2);
                }

                data.setChildItems(child_list);
                group_list.add(data);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Exception in DownloadBarcode method: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return group_list;
```

Comment: This is JSON format data not xml format .

Comment: @ZahidulIslam the value of "data"  object is xml.?

Comment: @Raghavendra Yes the value inside "data" object is in xml format, rest is in json format

Comment: @SheenaTyagi Which are all fields u need in that xml?

Comment: "data": "<sku>                                                         <barcode>000002014001</barcode>                                                 <path></path>                                                                       <alias_code></alias_code>                                      <color>GREY</color>                                              <price>10.50</price>                                                          <size>S</size>                                                                 <stock>0</stock>                                                          </sku>

Comment: a "data" tag can have n number of "sku"

Comment: Can u post how u r parsing json?

Comment: @Raghavendra code added

Comment: @SheenaTyagi The xml you are getting in "data" object is not well formed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ksoap2` for parsing XML response.
You can download `JAR` from [here](http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/index.html)

check this for more info -

1) https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android

2) [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-a-soap-web-service-on-android)

3) [how to Call ksoap web service from android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694605/how-to-call-ksoap-web-service-from-android)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a JSON format ,
and then I copy this data in the http://jsoneditoronline.org/ 
it shows like the picture below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euQPE.jpg)

So the data you have should be changed like this

```html
{
  "000002": {
    "ref": "000002",
    "barcodes": {
      "data": "<sku><barcode>000002014001</barcode><path></path><alias_code></alias_code><color>GREY</color><price>10.50</price><size>S</size><stock>0</stock></sku><sku><barcode>000002014002</barcode><path></path><alias_code></alias_code><color>GREY</color><price>10.50</price><size>M</size><stock>2</stock></sku><sku><barcode>000002014003</barcode><path></path><alias_code></alias_code><color>GREY</color><price>10.50</price><size>L</size><stock>1</stock></sku><sku>",
      "#datatype": "xml"
    }
  },
  "000012": {
    "ref": "000012",
    "barcodes": {
      "data": "<sku><barcode>000012030001</barcode><path></path><alias_code></alias_code><color>BLUE</color><price>19.99</price><size>S</size><stock>1</stock></sku><sku><barcode>000012030002</barcode><path></path><alias_code></alias_code><color>BLUE</color><price>19.99</price><size>M</size><stock>3</stock></sku><sku>",
      "#datatype": "xml"
    }
  },
"pager": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "limit": 50,
    "total": "354",
    "pages": 8
  }
}
```